# Как настроить перенос строк в monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

Хочу узнать как в [Monodevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/) настроить перенос строк (word wrap) в код и вообще поддерживает ли это свойство редактор Monodevelop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Увы по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413231/wordwrap-with-monodevelop-texteditor) я как понял пока перенос строк не поддерживается.

Comment: Угу, воз и ныне там: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/7415